# Spring boot JPA - Can't fetch paginated nested resources

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 2 entities - **Thread** and **Post**. **Thread** has many **Post**s.
Each entity had a repository and basic CRUD functionality works for each.

**My problem:** I can't find the way to retrieve a paginated collection of **Post**s associated with a particular **Thread**.

Of course I can fetch Thread by id and it oulls in the Posts aswell...but this doesn't suit my usecase. If a thread had 60 posts for example then I need to be able to paginate the results. This makes me feel like I should be calling the PostRepository directly and asking for only the posts that have a specific Thread ID.

This lead me to the following query method in my PostRepository:

```
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post p " +
        "JOIN Thread AS t " +
        "ON p.thread.id = t.id " +
        "WHERE t.id = :threadId")
Page<Post> findPostsByThreadId(@Param("threadId") long threadId, Pageable pageable);
```

Unfortunately this returns nothing. (It is worth pointing out that the posts *have* been persisted - I just can't query for them this way).

I will show a basic representation of my entities below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thread")
public class Thread {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private String state;

@OneToMany
private List<Post> posts;


public Thread() { }

@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    posts = new ArrayList<>();
    state = "OPEN";
}

@PreUpdate
public void preUpdate() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}

public void submitPost(Post newPost) {
    posts.add(newPost);
}

public Long getThisId() {
    return id;
}

public List<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post extends ResourceSupport {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private String postText;

@ManyToOne
private Thread thread;

public Post() { }

public Long getThisId() {
    return id;
}

public Thread getThread() { return thread; }

public String getPostText() {
    return postText;
}

public void setPostText(String postText) {
    this.postText = postText;
}

public void setThread(Thread thread) {
    this.thread = thread;
}
}
```

I am fairly new to JPQL so I may be making a silly mistake.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the `Thread` also persisted?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise I would not have been able to POST a the Posts into the thread in the first place.
Sorry I did not include my controller in the example but please assume that I already POSTed a Thread and the POSTed some Posts to it.

Comment: Does it work without pagination?

Comment: No but to be honest, I just found a rookie error in my code. I realised I had created a new Post model internally rather than deserialising it from the request body and...in doing so I had for some unknown reason comment out the line where I set the ThreadId - I am so sorry to waste your time; I can't believe I didn't see it!

Comment: You can answer or delete the question, I'm glad you made it

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I will delete the question then. :)

Comment: Does your JPQL query return data without pagination?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not answer the original problem, it would worth to mention that you DO NOT need to manually create that query. All you need is to define the name of the method in your repository interface (using the proper naming conventions) and let JPA do the rest:

```
Page<Post> findAllByThreadId(@Param("threadId") long threadId, Pageable pageable);
```

Less code: less chance to make a mistake.

If you use Data Rest too, it will also automatically create the appropriate REST endpoint for it.